# building a new pc - no display, no beeps

Tags: computer-building

Building a new pc using this motherboard: GA-MA785GMT-UD2H

and a 500W power supply (1 x 20 pin & 1 x 4 pin connectors).

The CPU fan, hard drive and power supply all spin up but no display on the monitor and no beeps.

Have tried:
taking out all of the memory and still no beeps

used a different power supply and still no display

I only have the Motherboard, memory, CPU, heat sink & fan & power supply connected.

Any ideas?

Do I have a faulty motherboard?

Comment: 1) How many RAM modules are you installing? 2) Are all of the modules the exact same size and speed? 3) What size and speed memory modules did you purchase? 4) Please provide a link to the memory modules you purchased.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? Would like to know what the answer was to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to check;

- Make sure all the power connectors are connected and secure
- If you can, try another monitor or a dedicated graphics card

The problem could be with CPU or motherboard. Did you use thermal paste when seating the heatsink?

Comment: I used a CPU box package and so the heat sink already had paste on it

Comment: In my experience, you are ALWAYS better off replacing the stock paste with some Arctic Silver (which will run you less than $10 for a small tube.) However, that is probably not your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Did you add a motherboard speaker?  GA-MA785GMT-UD2H doesn't come with a speaker so I added one from an older motherboard (it uses two of the pins in the same slot where the other connectors go for pwr, hdd_activity, rset) in order to get the beep codes - in my case a continuous series of long beeps :-(

Answer (score 2):

This probably does not apply to you but I recently had the same effects with an Intel motherboard.  It turned out that I plugged a 4pin VGA power connector into the CPU power socket (the power supply had two 4pin conectors and silly me did not read the labels).

Answer (score 2):

This happened to a friend of mine and it was very hard to tell by looking at it -- especially when the motherboard was installed: make sure the memory is inserted ALL THE WAY. You should hear a *click* as the clasps close on their own; you should not have to shut the clasps.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure memory is inserted and is inserted in the correct slots. Try the minimum amount of memory required for the motherboard and if that's less memory sticks than you have try swapping around to rule out bad memory.

Answer (score 1):

According to Crucial.com, your motherboard supports:

- 240-pin DDR3 DIMM Banking:   4 (2 banks of 2)
- Chipset:   AMD 785G
- DDR3 SDRAM Frequencies:   PC3-8500, PC3-10600, PC3-12800 and PC3-14400
- Error Detection Support:   Non-ECC only
- Graphics Support:   PCI Express x16
- Max Component Density:   2048
- Max Unbuffered DDR3 SDRAM:   16384MB
- Module Types Supported:   Unbuffered only
- Supported DRAM Types:   DDR3 SDRAM only

Please make sure of the following:

- The RAM is either PC3-8500, PC3-10600, PC3-12800 or PC3-14400
- All of your RAM is the SAME speed and size
- Your RAM is Unbuffered/Non-ECC (if it is classified as Server memory, ECC memory, or Buffered memory, you have RAM that will not work in your computer.)

More information:

http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=GA-MA785GMT-UD2H

Answer (score 0):

You might check power

instead of the std 4pin 12v cpu pwr you need the adapter for the 4pin to become an 8pin 12v cpu plug/